# Does a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism map a smooth hypersurface to a smooth hypersurface?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

We want to know if a smooth surface under a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism (infinitely differentiable with a infinitely differentiable inverse) map to a smooth surface too?
Further, it would be nice to understand what happens if the diffeomorphism was $C^k$ for some $k\geq 1$.

So far I have looked at these books:

i. Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee

ii. Analysis on Manifolds – Munkres.

However, I could not find a theorem statement that I could cite.
Here is a rough proof sketch, which may not be correct.

---

Definition. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$, and $N$ be its subset. Then $N$
is called a smooth n-dimensional submanifold of $M$ if for every $p \in N$ there exists a smooth
chart $(U, \phi)$ in $M$ such that $p \in U$ and $\phi(N \cap U) = \mathbb{R}^n \cap \phi(U)$, where $R^n$ is embedded into $R^m$
as the subspace $\{x_{n+1} = 0, \cdots, x_{m} = 0\}$.

Theorem: Suppose  $N$ is a smooth $n$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.  Consider $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$. $h(N)$ is a smooth $n$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$

Proof:
Let $Q=h(N)$. Consider a point $q \in Q$. For this point the corresponding preimage in $N$ is $p$, i.e., $h(p)=q$. We use the smooth chart containing $p$ to construct a smooth chart containing $q$ as follows.  Suppose $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth chart around $p$. Define $V=h(U)$ and $\psi = \phi \circ h^{-1}$. We can show that $V$ is an open set because $h$ is a homeomorphism and $U$ is an open set. Consider the chart $(V, \psi)$ on $Q$.  Next, let us simplify $\psi(Q \cap V) = \phi \circ h^{-1} ( h(N) \cap h(U)) = \phi ( N \cap U) = \mathbb{R}^n \cap \phi(U) = \mathbb{R}^n \cap \psi(V)$, where  $\mathbb{R}^n$ is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^m$ as the subspace $\{x_{n+1} = 0, \cdots, x_{m} = 0\}$. Also, $\psi(V)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ because it is equal to $\phi(U)$.

Observe that $\psi: V \rightarrow \psi(V)$ is a diffeomorphism because $\psi=\phi \circ h^{-1}$, composition of diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Did you actually try to prove this? What was the difficulty?

Comment: No, I did not know how to do it as I am new to the analysis of smooth manifolds.

Comment: Start by writing down the definition of a submanifold. This will get you half way through the proof. What is your definition of a submanifold?

Comment: I followed your advice @MoisheKohan. I would really appreciate if you see my proof attempt above and lmk where I am wrong.

Comment: No. Your confusion stems from the conflation of two notions: An abstract manifold (you got this definition right) and a **submanifold** (which you apply to submanifolds of ${\mathbb R}^d$ only for some reason, but that's fine). To solve this problem, you have to know the definition a submanifold: In the statement of your problem you should **assume** that $M$ is a submanifold of ${\mathbb R}^d$ and you should be proving that $N$ is also a submanifold of ${\mathbb R}^d$. Any decent book on differential topology will make a clear distinction between abstract manifolds and submanifolds.

Comment: I followed what u said @MoisheKohan. I would appreciate if u can see the claim and proof attempt and share your thoughts. I used https://www.math.arizona.edu/~izosimov/math534a/Submanifolds.pdf.

Comment: Your theorem does not make sense as stated since you did not explain in the statement what $Q$ is. Is $Q$ an abstract manifold? Then it is not even a subset of $R^k$ for any $k$. Is $Q$ a submanifold of $R^m$? Then there is nothing to prove. Is it a subset of $R^m$? Then what do you mean by a diffeomorphism $N\to Q$? A meaningful statement would be one where you start with a diffeomorphism $h: R^m\to R^m$.

Comment: Thanks @MoisheKohan. 
Yes, if I start with $h$ being a diffeomorphism, where $h:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$, then the above theorem statement is fine right?  Also, does the proof sketch look right?

Comment: Now, it is a clear statement and a clean proof.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!